# Use of undefined constant mascota - assumed 'mascota' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Tags: laravel-8

Creo estoy llamando mal el ID, si coloco un nuero estático cualquiera funciona y llena la tabla.
Pero cuando intento llamar al ID me da error.
[image: Me dice que el error esta en la linea 88]

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que dentro del Route como parámetro no puedes usar variables javascript, por lo que te recomiendo que primero crees la ruta con un parámetro, luego cambies el parámetro por la variable y finalmente asignes la ruta al formulario:

```
for(let mascota of datos) {
    var url = '{{ route("api.mascotaborrar", ":id") }}';
    url = url.replace(':id', mascota.id);
    masco.innerHtml += `
        ...
        <form action="${url}" method="POST">
           ...
```

Por favor, la próxima vez copia el código en formato texto para que podamos utilizarlo fácilmente.

Comment: Gracias me has ayudado mucho

Y claro, para próximas consultas lo haré de esa forma